# what are the available certifications in salesforce and which one is preferable

Tags: certification

i want to know which certification i have to do in salesforce,as of now i dont have any certificates.thanks in advance.As someone suggested me to take App Builder,but dumps are not availables.

Comment: You may find here....https://www.webassessor.com/wa.do?page=enterCatalog&branding=SALESFORCE&tabs=111
and preferred one is upon your interest and capability....

Comment: First go for ADM 201 this will be best for new sales-force learner........ then if you love configuration go for Advanced Admin then you have Platform App Builder and if you like customization part i mean coding go for  Developer 1 & Developer 2 & so on...........

Comment: Why are you looking for dumps - all the answers to the questions that you will be asked can be found by going through the relevant Certification workbook. Only way to learn is to practice and that will actually make you useful to work for somebody unlike someone who only learned how to pass a test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ben said, it is a very good idea to look into the Beginner Admin track first. This is because even if you're a developer looking to transition to Apex, there are so many declarative features on the Salesforce platform that you can leverage to do things without code. And the Admin track will give you an insight into what is possible to do via code and what isn't. Also, you'll learn about the data object model, which will be so helpful to you.

For this, there is a lot of information on [Trailhead](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en) you can learn.

More information on certs and good advice to follow can be found [here](http://www.salesforceben.com/new-salesforce-certifications-for-2015/), [here](https://www.udemy.com/salesforcecertification/) and [here](http://www.sfdc99.com/2014/10/02/guide-to-passing-all-salesforce-certifications/). A relatively cheap way to learn the Admin track, other than Trailhead, is to check out this very comprehensive course [here](https://www.udemy.com/salesforce-administrator/).

Salesforce has really become so broad now, and it continues to expand. So after you have taken the admin cert(s), you can then focus into an area which appeals most to you, be it Marketing or development or implementation etc.

[Salesforce University](http://salesforcedestinationsuccess.com/) continues to grow at a rapid pace, and the number of people who have certs and have Trailhead badges is increasing hugely. But it's really a combination of experience and certs which make you stand out and a smart way to get more experience is to volunteer your time via [Catchafire](https://www.catchafire.org/) and other websites.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

If you go to http://certification.salesforce.com/ there is lots of good information about the certification program.  I would suggest you start with the basic admin and then move to dev.  ( but this really depends on what your focus is )  Admin is a good place to start as it will give you an overview of the platform and features.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I definitely recommend this webpage http://www.sfdc99.com/, it also has tips&tricks to approve the most usual certifications.

Which one should you take depends on what are your role interests but I think for any developer admin & developer should be a must when you have some background on the salesforce developing world.